# Trying to find # duplicates in array - my function returns 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The goal is to find number of duplicate values in array.

**What I'm doing**: for each item in array, if not in temp array, add it, or else  count +=1.

```
function find_duplicate_in_array(arra1) {
        var temp=[];
        let count = 0;
        arra1.forEach(function (item) {
          if(!temp[item]) {
              temp.push(item);   
           } else {
              count=count+1;
           }
                    });
          console.log(temp);
          return count;
}

    let result=find_duplicate_in_array(["sam", "bob", "sam"]); 
    console.log(result);
```

Actaul Result: 0;
  Expected result:1 (TYPO, # of duplicated would be one);

**Why?**

Comment: You should use object for temp https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/54/

Comment: why do you want `2` as result?

Comment: @NenadVracar Why should I use object for temp? Why is array not working in this case? Please explain.

Comment: Because arrays are numerically indexed so you cannot check for element like this `temp[item]`, You could use `includes` or `indexOf` instead but I think using object is better solution in this case

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you actually want as a result is 1. There is a single duplicate in your provided array, and if you added one more "sam" there would be two. `temp[item]` does not look for values inside the array. What would work is `temp.includes(item)`, which does look for the specified item in the array.

Comment: this is the only answer that explains _why_ the author's code doesn't work.

Comment: Please help me understand: temp[item] does not look for values inside the array ?? What is it doing?

Comment: no: temp[item] search for a value indexed by the 'item' key. what you have to do is to check if your temp array includes or not your item. and you can do that using the method that Colby suggested you.

Comment: Running through a couple tests, it's as I expected: When `item` is **anything that is not a number**, it will result in `undefined` as a result when used in the syntax `arr[item]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attempt the problem using "Array.filter", "new Set", like below

```js
function find_duplicate_in_array(arr) {
  return [...new Set(arr.filter((d, i) => i != arr.lastIndexOf(d)))]
}

let res = find_duplicate_in_array(["sam", "bob", "sam", "nitish", "nn", "nn", "nn"])

console.log('Duplicate values ', res)

console.log('Duplicate values length', res.length)
```

Comment: wow, we are posting the answer almost the same time, I'm not js fans, but the origin question need to return the index of the duplicated item.

Comment: :) Did I miss anything in OP? Where is it mentioned that index is to be returned?

Answer (score 0):

there are several method to make it happen, here is the simplest one:

```
var findDuplicate = function(nums) {
    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < nums.length ; j++)
            if(i != j && (nums[i] == nums[j])) return nums[j];
    return -1;
};
```

or you may tried to resolve it in other language: such as dict in python

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the indices in an object and filter the values by the length of the indices array. Then return an array of arrays of key and indices.

```js
function find_duplicate_in_array(array) {
    var temp = {};
    array.forEach((item, index) => (temp[item] = temp[item] || []).push(index));
    return Object
        .entries(temp)
        .filter(([, { length }]) => length > 1);
}

let result = find_duplicate_in_array(["sam", "bob", "sam"]);
console.log(result);
```